# Macbook Pro Application Switcher automatically moves to far right?

Tags: macos, keyboard, window-manager, application-switcher

Apologies if this has been asked somewhere. I tried searching for a solution to this for a while to no avail.

When I press CMD + TAB on my Macbook Pro (Yosemite 10.10.3) to open the application switcher, normal behavior allows you to release the TAB key and hold CMD to keep the switcher window open, then tap TAB as necessary to reach the desired application. Instead, my machine continues cycling to whatever application is on the far right, as if I were also holding down the TAB key.

I haven't noticed any odd behavior anywhere else. I tried repairing my disk (which did need to be repaired), but now everything says OK and the behavior still persists.

Let me know if any other information would be applicable. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having this same issue. I use Command+Tab very frequently, and I would say about 50% of the time lately, when I switch applications, the selector doesn't stop. It just flows all the way to the right. I am running the 10.10.4 beta preview which might have something to do with it. To the original poster, are you running a beta or a normal public release?

Answer (score 0):

The key [pardon the pun] is Key Repeat Rate

System Prefs > Keyboard  > Keyboard

Switch repeat off to prevent it running away, or slow it down, or increase the delay…

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not the issue. If I were to hold the tab key down then repeat rate would come into play. But when I release tab the command key should not cause the switcher to cycle at all. Either way, I tried it and the problem persists.